# Why are models of spaCy more than 500MB compared to the lexicons used in TextBlob which are about 1MB?

Tags: model, textblob, spacy

If you go to the directories containing the models of spaCy you find files like data\en-1.1.0\deps\model with 433.881 KB, data\en-1.1.0\ner\model with 35.698 KB, data\en-1.1.0\pos\model with 11.524 KB and in data\en-1.1.0\vocab two binary files lexemes.bin with 81.096 KB and vec.bin with 206.562 KB, and strings.json with 18.371 KB. And of course several smaller files summing up to 812.694 KB in total. When loaded (which takes some time) main memory consumption increases by about 2.4 GB. In TextBlob the whole directory for english is about 2.299 MB. Why is this enormous difference of almost three orders of magnitude?